# how to find iOS 8 simulator in terminal?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, ios8.1

before i access `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`

I can't seem to find 8.0 and 8.1.

Is the location changed? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

Comment: BaSha, i'm looking for the sqlite file inside CoreSimulator. Is it here?

Comment: found it! Its under /CoreSimulator/"device id"/data/Containers/Data

Comment: yes, it is much work to find it. I had to check each folders one by one

Answer (score 1):

You can even use this tool to reach out the specific app bundle. It is upgraded for xCode 6. Here is how you can select your iPhone simulators from your task bar:

[image]

http://simpholders.com/